# Notification.BigPictureStyle doesn't work

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm trying to implement BigPictureStyle but it doesn't work. Push message working but it without big image. Image url is not null. I sent push with Adobe management. 
Also trying to use RemoteViews but it doesn't work too.
Please, help!

```
public class FCMListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    /*call sendNotification*/
}

private void sendNotification(String title,
                              String message,
                              String type,
                              String id,
                              String deepLink,
                              final String imageUrl,
                              Bundle fbPushBundle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    if (fbPushBundle != null)
        intent.putExtra("push", fbPushBundle);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    if (deepLink != null && !deepLink.isEmpty()) {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(type);
        intent.setData(uri);
    }
    intent.putExtra("type", type);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_push_app_icon))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_push_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(FCMListenerService.this, R.color.theme_yellow))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                    | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Bitmap largeImage = null;
    if (imageUrl != null) {
        try {
            largeImage = Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).get();
            if (largeImage!=null){
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(largeImage));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());

}
}
```

**Resolved**
It's just strange Xiaomi notifications. There are necessary to use two fingers to expand notification

Comment: you checked if largeImage not null when you set  setStyle?

Comment: largeImage is not null, I sure

Comment: you tried to load a local image before using Picasso?

Comment: yes, tried. There are another cause.
This problem resolved, thanks.

Comment: did you tried to expand the notification?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the content and title

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(img).setSummaryText(content).setBigContentTitle(msg))
```